# Is crypto-js considered as a standard encryption algorithms?

Tags: iphone, encryption, app-store

I want to release my app on apple store and I have to determine what type of encryption algorithms my app uses:

```
What type of encryption algorithms does your app implement?


1. Encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standard by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)

2. Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system

3. Both algorithms mentioned above

4. None of the algorithms mentioned above
```

In this app, I am using HTTPS and AES of [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) package.
Based on different answers, I found that using HTTPS is considered as using standard encryption methods and is now exempt from regulation, and by setting `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` to NO in the `Info.plist` can be addressed.

However, I don't know and couldn't find information about using "crypto-js".
So my question is whether AES is a standard encryption algorithm or not? If so, then adding `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` in `Info.plist` is enough?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The crypto-js package contains many algorithms that are mostly considered 'standard'. We don't know which algorithms you're using or how, so no definitive answer can be given. You could be *using* AES to implement your own home-grown encryption algorithm. Furthermore, the language of the questionnaire is poorly worded and ambiguous that even if you implemented your own home-grown encryption algorithm you could still honestly answer with #3.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  I tried to edit my question to make it more clear. Yes, I am using AES and enc to encrypt and decrypt some data (like user's password) in my app, nothing more, is it still #3 or #2 is sufficient?

Comment: Using `AES` in `crypto-js` should fall under #3. No idea about the Info.plist

Comment: Yes @gusto2  , you are right. I did some research and found that ASE is an standard algorithem but forgot to update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [CryptoJS docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) "Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) is a U.S. Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS)" and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) "AES is included in the ISO/IEC 18033-3 standard. AES became effective as a U.S. federal government standard on May 26, 2002, after approval by the U.S. Secretary of Commerce.", thus, AES is a standard encryption algorithm.